# ASP.NET Core 1.0 upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.0 Upgrade Authentication in ConfigureServices - How do I use Fields in Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working with code that has worked and need migrate from Core 1.0 to Core 2.0 and need to use and migrate Fields in the Services Authentication. How do I use Fields in Core 2.0? (I reviewed the Migration document at Microsoft too, but cannot find anything.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

and I'm having trouble with the following: (How do I add the following in Core 2.0)

```
Fields = { "email", "last_name", "first_name" },
```

Here's my code below.

ASP.NET Core 1.0

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
{
    AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Test:Facebook:AppId"],
    AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Test:Facebook:AppSecret"],
    Fields = { "email", "last_name", "first_name" },
});
```

Need to Migrate to ASP.NET Core 2.0

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Test:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Test:Facebook:AppSecret"];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fields` is read-only, but you can modify its *contents*. Taking your example, a code-level migration might look like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Test:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Test:Facebook:AppSecret"];
    facebookOptions.Fields.Clear();
    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("email");
    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("last_name");
    facebookOptions.Fields.Add("first_name");
});
```

However, this is not actually necessary as these are [set by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookOptions.cs#L31). See the code snippet from the source:

```
public FacebookOptions()
{
    // ...
    Fields.Add("name");
    Fields.Add("email");
    Fields.Add("first_name");
    Fields.Add("last_name");
    // ...
}
```

It looks like it wasn’t necessary even in the [previous version](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/rel/1.1.3/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook/FacebookOptions.cs#L29) of ASP.NET Core, but your code would work fine as you were just replacing the defaults (without `name`). If you really don’t want to request the `name`, you can use `facebookOptions.Fields.Remove(“name”)`.